# Programmatically download RDP file of Azure Resource Manager VM

Tags: rest, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I am able to create VM from a custom image using Azure resource management sdk for .net. Now,  I want to download the RDP file for virtual machine programmatically. I have searched and able to find Rest API for azure 'Classic' deployments which contains an api call to download RDP file but i can't find the same in Rest API for 'ARM' deployment. Also, I can't find any such Method in .net sdk for azure. 
Does there any way exist to achieve that? Please guide..

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: In my experience, the API docs aren't up to date and the functionality actually works. Have you tried it? Or are you assuming that it doesn't work?

Comment: I actually dint find a call for ARM. please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163607.aspx
what request url i could try?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a direct way to download the RDP file from the ARM REST APIs, but there is a Powershell cmdlet (Get-AzureRmRemoteDesktopFile). If you trace the ARM calls the cmdlet makes via Fiddler, you can see it builds the file using a series of calls to determine the public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to get the RDP file, but you can get all the information you need from the deployment itself.  On the deployment, you can set outputs for the values you need like the publicIp dns.  See this:

https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/blob/master/VMCSEInstallFilePS/azuredeploy.json#L213-215

If your environment is more complex (load balancers, network security groups) you need to account for port numbers, etc.